# Dataframe records query issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Env: Spark 1.6, Scala

Hi
I have records in Dataframe like bellow

```
reportTime               serverNAme     channel     viewer  
2017-01-12 19:16:58.76  MTRL28DSERV722  Channel1    1192
2017-01-12 19:16:59.213 MTRL28DSERV722  Channel1    668
2017-01-12 19:17:05.193 BBBN23DSERV000  Channel1    795
2017-01-12 19:17:01.15  BBBN23DSERV000  Channel1    700

2017-01-12 19:16:58.76  MTRL28DSERV722  Channel3    100
2017-01-12 19:16:59.213 MTRL28DSERV722  Channel3    110
2017-01-12 19:17:05.193 BBBN23DSERV000  Channel3    200
2017-01-12 19:17:01.15  BBBN23DSERV000  Channel3    50
```

I need output : latest viewers from each server by channel- so that

```
2017-01-12 19:16:59.213 MTRL28DSERV722  Channel1    668
2017-01-12 19:17:05.193 BBBN23DSERV000  Channel1    795


2017-01-12 19:16:59.213 MTRL28DSERV722  Channel3    100
2017-01-12 19:17:05.193 BBBN23DSERV000  Channel3    200
```

How can I get result ? I don't want to register DF as temptable and use SQL on it as SQL is not optimized in Spark 1.6.
Thanks
Hossain

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `row_number` within each combination of `severName` and `channel`, in descending order of `reportTime`, and then use `where` to filter the first row within each group which should be the one with the most recent reportTime:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number    
val w = Window.partitionBy($"serverNAme", $"channel").orderBy($"reportTime".desc)

df.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).where($"rn" === 1).drop($"rn").show

+--------------------+--------------+--------+------+
|          reportTime|    serverNAme| channel|viewer|
+--------------------+--------------+--------+------+
|2017-01-12 19:17:...|BBBN23DSERV000|Channel3|   200|
|2017-01-12 19:16:...|MTRL28DSERV722|Channel3|   110|
|2017-01-12 19:17:...|BBBN23DSERV000|Channel1|   795|
|2017-01-12 19:16:...|MTRL28DSERV722|Channel1|   668|

+--------------------+--------------+--------+------+
```

Comment: Appreciating your help @Psidom. It is working for me